# Como acessar um metodo de uma ArrayList em outro frame?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

Classe Pessoa :

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }
    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }
    public String exibeDados(){
       return "\nNOME : "+this.getNome()+"\nIDADE : "+this.getIdade();
    }
    }
```

Frame Inicial :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TelaInicial extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList<Pessoa> p ;
    Pessoa pessoa;
    int contador=0,controlador=0;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\nNOME"+campoNome.getText() + "\nIDADE : " +campoIdade.getText();
    }
    public TelaInicial() {
        p = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        campoNome = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        campoIdade = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        botaoCadastrar = new javax.swing.JButton();
        botaoExibir = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("CADASTRO PESSOAS ");

        jLabel2.setText("NOME : ");

        jLabel3.setText("IDADE : ");

        botaoCadastrar.setText("CADASTRAR");
        botaoCadastrar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                botaoCadastrarActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        botaoExibir.setText("EXIBIR");
        botaoExibir.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                botaoExibirActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(96, 96, 96)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(botaoCadastrar, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addComponent(botaoExibir, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(campoIdade))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addComponent(campoNome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 199, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addContainerGap(41, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(25, 25, 25)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(campoNome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(campoIdade, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(botaoCadastrar)
                    .addComponent(botaoExibir))
                .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void botaoCadastrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        int idade = Integer.parseInt(campoIdade.getText());
        pessoa = new Pessoa(campoNome.getText(),idade);
        p.add(pessoa);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this," DADO CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO ");
        contador = contador + 1;

    }                                              

    private void botaoExibirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        ExibeFrame exibe = new ExibeFrame();
        exibe.setVisible(true);

        exibe.MostraTudo(p,pessoa);
    }                                           
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TelaInicial().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton botaoCadastrar;
    private javax.swing.JButton botaoExibir;
    private javax.swing.JTextField campoIdade;
    private javax.swing.JTextField campoNome;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Frame para Exibir :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ExibeFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public ExibeFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
    public void MostraTudo(ArrayList p,Pessoa pessoa){

        for(int i = 0;i < p.size();i++){
             areaDados.setText(p.get(i).getNome());
        }
         }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        areaDados = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("DADOS PESSOAS");

        areaDados.setColumns(20);
        areaDados.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(areaDados);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(146, 146, 146)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(171, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 253, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ExibeFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextArea areaDados;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Então, o problema está na parte do "Frame Exibir", exatamente no metodo **MostraTudo**, pois nela eu queria acessar o metodo getNome e getIdade do objeto pessoa que está no argumento acima, porém eu não consigo acessar esses metodos, somente o to String. O que eu faço para conseguir acessar esses metodos,eu queria fazer algo do tipo  `p.get(0).getNome()`. No frameInicial eu até consigo, mas como a caixa de texto é privada, então eu não consigo acessa-la de outro frame.

Comment: Voce ja fez essa pergunta e possui 2 respostas.

Comment: Desculpe, mas é que dessa vez eu estou com problemas em exibir os dados, aquele tópico era para colocar os dados. Nesse eu não estou conseguindo acessar os metodos get e set no outro frame D:

Comment: Edita a pergunta(inclusive o titulo) explicando melhor o que o codigo deveria fazer, e em qual ponto do codigo está sua dificuldade para que eu possa reabri-la.

Comment: Alterei o titulo e melhorei a descrição, da uma olhadinha lá

Comment: Na verdade continua sendo duplicata. Da uma lida nas respostas das duas perguntas que marquei la no topo, elas respondem sua duvida.